# Apple Sign In - retrieve name and email

Tags: firebase-authentication, apple-id, sign-in-with-apple

From the documentation I could find out that only upon first login into my app, the users name and email will be returned with the credential. So i go ahead and save these to my backend.

Now if the user decides to delete his account, I delete all his data from my backend (thats propably what the user wants me to do. And isnt that what i have to do anyway according to some privacy laws or what not?).

Now if the user ever decides to change his mind another time and install the app, will i not be able to fetch username and email? No matter what i do? Or did I miss some kind of user.ultimateSignoutAndDelete(for: .ever) to be able to fetch userdata on his next sign in?

Maybe this scenario seems a bit constructed but when testing apple-sign-in you stumble upon that immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you trying to find out if there is a way to recover a deleted account?

Comment: I was wondering if theres any way to delete the connection between the apple id and my app. So that on a future sign in the user data would be passed again.

Answer (score 0):

Once you delete a Firebase Auth account, there is no way to recover any information from that account.  All links between the user and your projects are gone.  The user will have to create a new account.

Comment: I think that this is not correct. Not all links are gone. Even after deleting the auth account, apple sign-in knows about the "history" and doesnt pass username etc. anymore. So i was wondering if theres a way to cut even this link. Thats my question actually. Because i do have to create a new account in fact, but no data is passed and i would have to prompt the user to type the info himself.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more clear about what all you're actually observing, along with code that demonstrates the behavior you're trying to avoid?  I will point out that Firebase Auth user deletion is final - you are probably observing some other behavior.

Comment: I found out how the account is still connected. Its an expected apple sign in behaviour and can be solved as in this article under 7.)  https://medium.com/developerinsider/ios-13-how-to-integrate-sign-in-with-apple-in-your-application-c21f579aca7